# How to override a function of the class KeyEvent?

Tags: java, android, keyevent

I've been having an issue with overriding the method: onKeyDown
I'm trying to create a plugin that is to be used in unity.

The error i'm getting is: "Method does not override method from its superclass"
The @Override is underlined with this error

The aim is to know when the power key is pressed.

In the constructor, i have added the super method to resolve another error that occurred after adding extends KeyEvent. The error read: "There is no default constructor available in 'android.view.KeyEvent'"

I have tried this but the method does not show up in the list
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/overriding-methods-of-a-superclass.html

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class PowerButtonPlugin extends KeyEvent {

    private static final PowerButtonPlugin ourInstance = new PowerButtonPlugin();

    public static PowerButtonPlugin getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private PowerButtonPlugin() {
        super(0, 26); //event: press down, button power key

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {           
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just checked the api of KeyEvent, I don't see a method called onKeyDown, so the error you are getting is quite understandable

Comment: True. The correct api would be Activity!